# Display settings on Try Ubuntu dektop 22.04 unusable

Tags: drivers, display, 22.04

When I use the 22.04 iso (on a usb drive) to Try Ubuntu Desktop, I get a display that is unreadable... It uses light yellow text on a white or yellow background!

I managed to get into the Display settings, and none of the refresh rates are the 77Hz that  works on my installed 22.04. I don't see (of what I struggle to read) way to get a setting that "just works", like it did in all past versions of Try Ubuntu.
I'm running on an HP Envy laptop with an nVidia GeForce RTX graphics chip, Intel core i7 processor.

[image: Try Ubuntu Display Settings Menu]

Comment: You mat try the option with "safe graphics".

Comment: I found a usb drive with 21.04, and it worked fine. The problem is with 22.04.

Comment: I too can't use it, there is no way to get to the next buttons and no clear way to change the resolution

Answer (score 0):

22.10 works. After upgrading I don't have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use safe graphics mode during boot and change from dedicated graphics to integrated graphics or switchable graphics in BIOS